# PHP AMQP Internal Server Error

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using the compiled and installed AMQP on my Debian Squeeze server to connect to my RabbitMQ server.
I'm using a following commands in a class, which I'm instantiating:

```
$this->_amqpConnection = new AMQPConnection($arrRmqConfig);
$this->_amqpConnection->connect();

// creating the amqp channel is sufficient to throw the errors
$this->_amqpChannel = new AMQPChannel($this->_amqpConnection);

$this->_amqpExchange = new AMQPExchange($this->_amqpChannel);
$this->_amqpExchange->setName($strExchange);

$this->_amqpExchange->publish($strMessage, 'dco.marker', AMQP_MANDATORY);
```

I get lighttpd error messages and a HTTP-500 response:

```
2012-09-10 17:43:01: (mod_fastcgi.c.2568) unexpected end-of-file (perhaps the fastcgi process died): pid: 11358 socket: unix:/var/tmp/sockets/php-fastcgi.socket11050-99 
2012-09-10 17:43:01: (mod_fastcgi.c.3356) response not received, request sent: 1002 on socket: unix:/var/tmp/sockets/php-fastcgi.socket11050-99 for /index.php?, closing connection
```

Publishing messages and debugging the code is working. I'm wondering why the program runs till the end but still produces an internal server error.

Can anyone reproduce this or has an idea?

thanks

Comment: you're missing a ; on your final line...could that be the problem?

Comment: thanks for the info, but thats just a copy&paste error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like a newer Version fixed he problem